# How to determine the directory in which a running Haskell script or application lives?

Tags: haskell, path, absolute-path

I have a Haskell script that runs via a shebang line making use of the `runhaskell` utility.  E.g...

```
#! /usr/bin/env runhaskell
module Main where
main = do { ... }
```

Now, I'd like to be able to determine the directory in which that script resides *from within the script, itself*.  So, if the script lives in `/home/me/my-haskell-app/script.hs`, I should be able to run it from anywhere, using a relative or absolute path, and it should know it's located in the `/home/me/my-haskell-app/` directory.

I thought the functionality available in the `System.Environment` module might be able to help, but it fell a little short.  `getProgName` did not seem to provide useful file-path information.  I found that the environment variable `_` (that's an underscore) would *sometimes* contain the path to the script, as it was invoked; however, as soon as the script is invoked via some other program or parent script, that environment variable seems to lose its value (and I am needing to invoke my Haskell script from another, parent application).

Also useful-to-know would be whether I can determine the directory in which a pre-compiled Haskell executable lives, using the same technique or otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [FindBin](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/FindBin) package which seems to suit your needs and it also works for compiled programs.

Answer (score 8):

As I understand it, this is historically tricky in *nix. There are libraries for some languages to provide this behavior, including FindBin for Haskell:

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/FindBin

I'm not sure what this will report with a script though. Probably the location of the binary that runhaskell compiled just prior to executing it.

Also, for compiled Haskell projects, the Cabal build system provides data-dir and data-files and the corresponding generated `Paths_<yourproject>.hs` for locating installed files for your project at runtime.

http://www.haskell.org/cabal/release/cabal-latest/doc/users-guide/authors.html#paths-module

Comment: The FindBin package seems to work okay for runhaskell-based scripts too.

Answer (score 6):

For compiled executables, In GHC 7.6 or later you can use [System.Environment.getExecutablePath](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-Environment.html#v%3agetExecutablePath).

```
getExecutablePath :: IO FilePathSource

  Returns the absolute pathname of the current executable.
  Note that for scripts and interactive sessions, this is the path to the
  interpreter (e.g. ghci.)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is [executable-path](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/executable-path) which worked with my `runghc` script. [FindBin](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/FindBin) didn't work for me as it returned my current directory instead of the script dir.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way to determine script path from Haskell (which is a real pity IMHO). However, as a workaround, you can wrap your Haskell script inside a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

SCRIPT_DIR=`dirname $0`

runhaskell <<EOF
main = putStrLn "My script is in \"$SCRIPT_DIR\""
EOF
```